# SQL Insert parameter value and value from another table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm unable to find a solution online for my question. If it is even possible, how do I write an SQL Insert statement that uses parameter values as well as selecting a value from another table.

Example:

```
"INSERT INTO Users (user_name, user_csn, user_adid, user_contact, user_adminpriviledge, user_datestart, user_active, user_team)
                 VALUES (@username, @usercsn, @useradid, @usercontact, @userauth, @userstart, @useractive, @userteam = (SELECT team_id FROM teaminfo WHERE team_name = '" & ddlAddTeam.SelectedValue & "'))"
```

I understand that the example is wrong, just trying my best to represent what I'm looking for in code.

Also another question would be regarding aliasing and datareaders. I seem to be unable to do "reader("column_name")" for aliased column names?

Example:

```
query = "SELECT u.*, t.team_name FROM Users u
    JOIN teaminfo t ON u.user_team = t.team_id WHERE user_csn = '" & GV.userCSN & "'"
```

I tried to use

```
reader("u.user_name")
```

but failed as well.

Comment: Are you using it in some code? Like C#?

Comment: Using it in VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need other syntax of insert operation: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...`:

```
INSERT INTO Users (user_name, user_csn, user_adid, user_contact, user_adminpriviledge, user_datestart, user_active, user_team) 
SELECT @username, @usercsn, @useradid, @usercontact, @userauth, @userstart, @useractive, team_id --<--not here's your column
FROM teaminfo 
WHERE team_name = @param
```

Also, it looks like it's .NET (C# or VB code), so you you are prone to SQL injection concatenating you string with parameters!

In my SQL I already put `@param` in proper place, then with `SqlCommand` you are probably using, you have to call method `Add`on `SqlCommand.Paramteres` collection, and then supplly it with value of `ddlAddTeam.SelectedValue`.

Try this code:

```
Using connection = New SqlConnection("connString")
    Using com = New SqlCommand
        com.Connection = connection
        com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (user_name, user_csn, user_adid, user_contact, user_adminpriviledge, user_datestart, user_active, user_team) 
                           Select @username, @usercsn, @useradid, @usercontact, @userauth, @userstart, @useractive, team_id --<--Not here's your column
                           From teaminfo
                           Where team_name = @param"
        com.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlAddTeam.SelectedValue
        connection.Open()
    End Using
End Using
```

And for column alises: in data reader you use column aliases **without table name** (`u` before the dot in ou example). Try to give aliases to all your columns to avoid such problems.

Comment: What about the JOIN portion? I saw similar examples to what you provided but didn't know how it worked. Would the Select portion not mean that the parameter values are obtained from teaminfo table?

Comment: @LimYX I told, that you should add aliases to your columns to avoid errors (it's optional, if you are sure column names ar unique, then, as I said, use only column name, without table name!).

Comment: This particular error appears, '"The parameterized query '(@username varchar(7), @usercsn nvarchar(10),@useradid nvarchar(' expects the parameter '@param', which was not supplied"'. Using it as how you stated in your updated answer and the way i did it 
'cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", ddlAddTeam.SelectedValue)'

both didnt seem to work

Comment: Because you have lot more parameters! You have to add everyone of it using `Parameters.Add` (`AddWithValue` isn't recommended, since it make SQL "guess" the type).

Comment: Ah ok got it, thanks for the help and clarification! Also if you don't mind me asking as well, what about in the case of an update? Do I follow similarly like 
"Update Users SET user_name = @username, user_team = (SELECT team_id FROM teaminfo WHERE team_name = @teamname) WHERE (condition)"

Comment: Well, try it and in case of problems, you could ask another question

Answer (score 0):

The data source for an [`INSERT` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can be a `SELECT` statement—see the `<dml_table_source>` part of the statement definition at the linked page—and a `SELECT` statement can include parameters in the select list. Here's a simple example:

```
declare @Target table (Id bigint, Datum char(1));
declare @Source table (Id bigint);
declare @Datum char(1) = 'X';
insert @Source values (1);

insert @Target
select
    Id = S.Id,       -- Value from another table
    Datum = @Datum   -- Parameter
from
    @Source S;
```

There are more examples at the page linked above; scroll down to the "Inserting Data From Other Tables" section header.

Also, if you're going to build a query in (C#?) code as you've shown in your example, you should really pass any arguments as parameters rather than trying to build them directly into the query text. Read up on [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) to see why.

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT query should be like

```
"INSERT INTO Users (user_name, user_csn, user_adid, user_contact, user_adminpriviledge, user_datestart, user_active, user_team)
                 VALUES (@username, @usercsn, @useradid, @usercontact, @userauth, @userstart, @useractive,  (SELECT team_id FROM teaminfo WHERE team_name = @userteam ))"
```

Second when fetching from reader it should be like :

```
reader("user_name") // I am not sure about this. You can put break point and open the object in watch window
```